# Convert NSDate to NSString time issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have this `NSDate`:

```
2013-03-14 17:35:00 +0000
```

And I try to convert it to `NSString` with this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
[formatter stringFromDate:item.startdate];
```

And what I get is:

```
03/14/2013 05:35:00
```

How can I fix it to give me the date with the time as in the date?

Comment: so what ,you only want date not time?

Comment: no i want the time too

Comment: The time is there. 05:35:00 If you want 24hr time then say so in the question. Also try using HH instead of hh.

Comment: I really don't see the issue. You get the date and the time in a string with your preferred date format. Is the problem 24hr-related and the way the date is presented?

Comment: You want to keep the difference from GMT (+0000) in the final string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `HH` instead of `hh` in your time   and it is good idea to set the timeZone also

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
[timeFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
NSString *newTime = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:[[NSDate alloc]init] ];
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want `HH` for 24-hour clock:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
```

However I noticed this in the [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html) which might affect you:

> In iOS, the user can override the default AM/PM versus 24-hour time
>   setting. This may cause NSDateFormatter to rewrite the format string
>   you set.

Answer (score 1):

`[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"];`

Use `H` instead of `h` to get the 24-hour formatted time.